# Capybara/Selenium - Is there a way to click a link that was isolated but has no unique identifier or content?

Tags: ruby, selenium, capybara

I'm trying to click a link with **Capyabara/Selenium**.

It's a pin link on a Bing map, [example can be found here](http://www.astonmartin.com/en/dealers).

I can iterate through the 161 links with the `all(…).each`:

```
within(".map") do
  all("a.dealer-pin").each do |link|
    click_link(link)
  end
end
```

But the `click_link(link)` throws an error:

```
Capybara::ElementNotFound: 
Unable to find link 
#<Capybara::Node::Element tag="a" 
path="/html/body/form/article/div/div/section/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[3]/div/a[1]">
```

**Those links have neither a unique identifier nor a content (image tag) that is unique or has a unique identifier.**

Answer (score 0):

Like the error is hinting, each DOM element can be referenced by its XPath which is similar, but more specific, than standard CSS selectors. You can the Path within the Chrome inspector by right clicking on the specific node.

Be careful testing something that's too specific. It's likely going to be fragile and break often making a test that's hard to maintain.

Relevant capybara doc: http://www.rubydoc.info/github/jnicklas/capybara/master/Capybara/Node/Finders

Comment: When I copy xpath for the `a` tag: `//*[@id="null"]`. For the `img` inside it I get: `//*[@id="null"]/img`.

Answer (score 0):

Since you already have the link element you just have to call `click` on it - `click_link` finds links by their id, title, or text contents (also alt attribute of a nested img) - but you have already found them with a normal css query

```
within(".map") do
  all("a.dealer-pin").each do |link|
    link.click
  end
end
```